# Angular 9 : How to import and use a module in lazy loaded component?

Tags: angular, ivy, devextreme, angular9, devextreme-angular

I needed an HTML editor (From DevExtreme) in my Application. Since it needs to be used on different pages based on authorisation mechanisms, I decided to externalise the editor in a component that can be loaded lazily.

However after externalising it, I get this error:
['dx-html-editor' is not a known element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C0cX.png)

I know that in order to solve this issue, we normally need to import the 'DxHtmlEditorModule' in the corresponding module of the component. Since we are dealing with a lazy-loaded component, the component is not declared in any module.

How to solve this issue of using a component from a 3rd party library in a lazy-loaded component?

Comment: What does the new structure look like? i.e. how are you pulling the modules together?

Comment: For the time being, I have only 1 module (app.module.ts)
The html-editor-component(lazily loaded) is in a shared folder (not a module) and this component contains the html-editor from DevExtreme